# Google's robots.txt Tester for googlebot throws error on Disallow: .idea

Tags: phpstorm, magento-1.9, robots.txt, googlebot

Google's robots.txt Tester for googlebot throws error on `Disallow: .idea`.

However, it reports 0 Errors and 0 Warnings.

[image: screen shot of error with no errors.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your robots.txt file *does* contains errors, but Google's testing tool is not reporting them correctly.

First, the errors. You have several directives where the path does not start with a slash, e.g.:

```
Disallow: CVS
Disallow: .svn
Disallow: .git
...
```

[Google's robots.txt specification](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt#group-member-records) says this is not allowed:

> The [path] value, if specified, is to be seen relative from the root of the website for which the robots.txt file was fetched (using the same protocol, port number, host and domain names). **The path value must start with "/"** to designate the root.

To fix this, you need to always specify a path that starts with a slash. In your case, you will probably need to use wildcards, e.g.:

```
Disallow: /*CVS
Disallow: /*.svn
Disallow: /*.git
...
```

The Google testing tool does not seem to be reporting these as errors. (The red bar does not indicate an error, it just indicates which directive is doing the blocking.) These *are* errors, however. Their behavior is undefined, and will almost certainly not be the behavior you want.